# Avoiding App Engine Authentication

Tags: java, google-app-engine

How do I configure my java app engine app so that one is not asked to login in order to make requests to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the normal mode of operation.  You shouldn't have to do anything.

Look at your web.xml file beneath WEB-INF folder.  Make sure there are no security-constraint's specified for your servlet.